# error: nodemon app crashed waiting for file changes before starting

Tags: node.js, backend

When I run my node.js code I get this error :

```
PS C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Full Stack\nodeJS\Project 2> nodemon index.js
[nodemon] 3.0.2
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
server is runing on port 3000...
node:events:492
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

AggregateError
    at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1114:18)
    at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1667:5)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
    at Connection._notifyError (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Full Stack\nodeJS\Project 2\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:252:12)
    at Connection._handleFatalError (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Full 
Stack\nodeJS\Project 2\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:183:10)
    at Connection._handleNetworkError (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Full Stack\nodeJS\Project 2\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:196:10)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)      
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3) 
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  fatal: true,
  [errors]: [
    Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3306
        at createConnectionError (node:net:1634:14)
        at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1664:40) {
      errno: -4078,
      code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '::1',
      port: 3306
    },
    Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
        at createConnectionError (node:net:1634:14)
        at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1664:40) {
      errno: -4078,
      code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 3306
    }
  ]
}

Node.js v20.9.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I have tried to close the connection and restart but the problem is still